# Multi data save with diffrent date field in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Mabey You know how I can save multi data with periodically date (+ ? week) in loop ?

In form user select start date and in loop save row 4 times with date + 1 week :D

```
$order = new Order;
$order->user_id = $user->id;
$order->save();

$books = [];

$date = new DateTime(Input::get('date'));

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $book = new Book;
    $book->date = ????;

    $books[] = $book;
}

$order->books()->saveMany($books);
```

Comment: Please include a minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. In other words, include what you have done so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, but I'm fresh user :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though its always a Datetime object, you should still be able to iterate through values with date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i week") ); to get the values you need where $i iterates from 1 to 4. Note: first time answerer on mobile!  :-)

Comment: Got it. Php's strtotime will use a base date before +$i weeks.  So if that user date is $userDate then: strtotime("$userDate +$i weeks") should work.

Comment: But first date is select by user and i don't want add 1 week to first date :(

Comment: Okay then iterate with $i starting with zero +0 weeks is okay.